# How to show that for $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^2}{n^2+1}=1$ we should pick $n \geq [\sqrt \epsilon ] + 1$

Tags: real-analysis

I am watching real analysis lectures. The lecturer notes down the following sequence with a limit:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} = 1$$

To see which $N$ we have to pick for an arbitrary $\epsilon$ he performs the following

$$\left|\frac{n^2}{n^2+1} - 1 \right| = \frac{1}{n^2+1} < \frac{1}{n^2} < \epsilon$$

He then claims that the inequality will hold for:

$$n \geq [\sqrt{\epsilon}] + 1$$

But I get the following...

$$\frac{1}{n^2} < \epsilon \\ n^2 > \frac{1}{\epsilon} \\ n > \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$$

How can I get his result? He has a great or **equal** bound plus he somehow gets a whole part (square brackets) from somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: If $\epsilon=0,1$, then does he claim that the inequality hold for $n\geq [\sqrt{\epsilon}]+1$? It means $n\geq 1$, but $\dfrac{1}{1^2}<0,1$ is false... What do you think?

Comment: ahh.. he made a mistake. It is supposed to be $n \geq [1/ \sqrt{\epsilon}] + 1$. So he got same answer as me, and then he says that it will also hold in the just mentioned case. I probably need to think a bit about this still, because I do not see where he gets this whole number from.

Comment: It looks like the $<1/n^2$ is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, he made a mistake. It should be $n\geq [\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}]+1$. The whole part is just because you want $n$ to be an integer, not any real number. So you take the whole part instead of $\epsilon+1$.